# Reading from a specific row/column from and excel csv file

Tags: python, excel, csv, export-to-csv

I am a beginner at Python and I'm looking to take 3 specific columns starting at a certain row from a .csv spreadsheet and then import each into python.

For example

> I would need to take 1000 rows worth of data from column F starting at
>   row 12.
>
> I've looked at options using cvs and pandas but I can't figure out how
>   to have them start importing at a certain row/column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Formatting your question correctly will go a long way to getting you the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If the spreadsheet is not huge, the easiest approach is to load the entire CSV file into Python using the csv module and then extract the required rows and columns. For example:

```
import csv
rows = list(csv.reader(file('Book1.csv', 'rb')))
data = [column[5] for column in rows[11:11+1000]]
```

will do the trick. Remember that Python starts numbering from 0, so `column[5]` is column F from your spreadsheet and `rows[11]` is row 12.

Answer (score 0):

CSV files being text files, there is no way to read a certain line. You will have to read line per line, and count... Have a look at the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) in Python, which will explain how to (easily) read lines. [Particularly this sectio](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader)n.